# Set Android Activity To Fullscreen WITHOUT changing the Theme

Tags: android, xamarin.android

this is the top of my xamarin android activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "XY", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",
     ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen")]
```

This does however effect the theme.
I'm using a seekbar that looks TERRIBLE with this theme. When I just leave the Theme part out, then the activity is no longer fullscreen and has this nasty little header but the seekbar looks good...
There has to be an easy way of just putting the activity to fullscreen WITHOUT changing the theme. Can you guys help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hope it helps:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

in Xamarin:
set the following flags in the activities OnCreate method:

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
```

Comment: thank yoiu, but unfortunately this is in java and xamarin is c# :)

Comment: yes I heard about it, I found somthing and I edited my answare

Comment: thanks again, unfortuanellty this doesnt do anything :(

Comment: oh sorry: if i leave out the second line of code, ti does in fact hide the top bar, but not the big banner saying the name of the activity. but its getting closer :)

Answer (score 0):

Update, I have found a workaround:

```
Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Using this theme in the header, will affect the overall theme, but since the standart theme is the HOLO one, it will set the standart theme to fullscreen. So this will work and also show you the prettier seekbar ;)

Thanks everybody!